# index.php not automatically read by localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost

I just installed Apache, php and MySQL manually in windows 8. It works fine

but the problem is when i try to open the directory in browser it auto opens index.html but not index.php

for ex: i have following folder structure

htdocs->folder1->index.php

if i access "localhost/folder1/index.php" it loads fine, but if i access"localhost/folder1" then it will show all the files and folder in that folder.

Is there anyway I can make localhost open index.php open automatically and not show files inside that folder?

Comment: You installed a bunch of *nix-native technologies on a developer preview of Windows that's not slated to be released for over a year? There's no way this is on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) directive is set correctly in you apache configuration file e.g.

DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm

Answer (score 1):

locate your server config DirectoryIndex definition in apache config file(s) and add index.php to whatever is already there. you can also have a DirectoryIndex per vhost. Or per directory. or inside a .htaccess. see [mod_dir directoryIndex documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)